# How Do I Find Outdated Policies in LoadBalancers

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, jmespath

What am I doing wrong here?  I can’t find a good example and I need to find the old policies in all my accounts:

```
aws elb describe-load-balancers --profile $account --region $region --load-balancer-name $loadbalancer --query 'LoadBalancerDescriptions[?Policies.OtherPolicies[*]!=`null`]|[?contains(Policies.OtherPolicies[*],`ELBSecurity`)].[LoadBalancerName, Policies.OtherPolicies[]]'
```

I know that the one particular $account/$region/$loadbalancer has OtherPolicies that match the criteria.

Comment: NOTE:  I just want the ones with the selected Policies.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all policies for elb by performing the [describe-load-balancer-policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elb/describe-load-balancer-policies.html) command.

Answer (score 0):

```
while read account; do
    while read region; do
            for loadbalancer in $(aws elb describe-load-balancers --profile $account --region $region --query 'LoadBalancerDescriptions[*].[LoadBalancerName]' --output text); do
                    while read policy; do
                            aws elb describe-load-balancer-policies --profile $account --region $region  --load-balancer-name $loadbalancer --query "PolicyDescriptions [?contains(PolicyName,'$policy')].[PolicyName, PolicyTypeName]" >> $account'_'$loadbalancer'_policies.txt'
                    done < $policies
            done
    done < $regions
done < $inputfile
```